# Ionic 4 bounce effect

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, capacitor

I would like to how i can get the bounce effect thats enabled in IOS for ion contents to work with android as well. I tried the has-bouncing="true" but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Did you find a working solution? If so, please answer your question.

Comment: @Dave nope, i ended up not going through with it if anyone know what can be that would be great

Answer (score -1):

This is the property for that `forceOverscroll`

> If true and the content does not cause an overflow scroll, the scroll
>   interaction will cause a bounce. If the content exceeds the bounds of
>   ionContent, nothing will change. Note, the does not disable the system
>   bounce on iOS. That is an OS level setting.

Url: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/content#properties